# How to support a large game when the max supported size is 2GB

Tags: android

My game with downsized textures for mobile and with LZ4 compression is around 6.5 GB for Nintendo Switch.
Now I'm thinking of doing a version for Android.
But the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery
say that max supported size limit for everything is 2 GB. Much less than 6.5 GB that I have.
What are my options?
Is there any Google/Android secret I'm not aware of? Or am I forced to use a third party hosting solution to store my own files and download them in game? If yes, anyone has any recommendations what's good?

Comment: updated your title to be bit more descriptive and to actually ask a question, you're welcome to change it back though. realistically i believe you're going to have to host the files and download once the game starts